# Change time value of a packet in a pcap file manually

Tags: networking, wireshark, libpcap, wireshark-dissector

I have a question. I want to change the time value of a packet in a pcap. when we open a pcap in wireshark, we see a timestamp value in 2nd column after the packet serial numbers.
I want to change the time value of the packets. Though I am able to do the same but face a problem like below.

Let's say current time value showed for the packet in wireshark is 0.960727
I want to add 100000 to this time stamp.
Now the new stamp for the packet becomes 0.1060727 which ideally should be 1.060727.
If you open any pcap file in wireshark, you will never find a time value of more than 6 digits after decimal point.
But when I add this value I get 7 numbers after decimal point.

Could anhyone please let me know how can I make the time value to 1.060727 instead of 0.1060727 ?

Thank you for your suggestions here.

Regards,
Som

Comment: If I add 100000 to 0.960727 it gives 100000.960727

Comment: Later in your question it seems more that you want to multiply by 10.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to do, but I'm going to take a guess that you are attempting to manually modify the timestamp of a single packet by editing the binary capture file.  Assuming the file format is a [`.pcap`](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) file, then I suppose you're attempting to add 100000 microseconds to the timestamp of one particular packet?

Assuming this is the case, then you need to locate the packet header's `ts_sec` and `ts_usec` values and add `0x000186a0` microseconds to the current value of the `ts_usec` value, but if this value exceeds `0x000f423f` (i.e., it's greater than or equal to 1 second), then you should add `0x00000001` to the `ts_sec` value and subtract `0x000f4240` from the newly computed `ts_usec` value.

One important thing to keep in mind is whether the `.pcap` file is written in big-endian or litte-endian format.  This is determined by the so-called `magic number` (`0xa1b2c3d4` implying big-endian and `0xd4c3d2a1` implying little-endian).  Make sure you perform the addition/subtraction using the correct byte order of the `ts_usec` value and `ts_sec` value if appropriate, and make sure you write the bytes back to the `ts_usec` and `ts_sec` fields in the expected byte order of the file; otherwise your resulting timestamp will not be correct.

If this is not what you're attempting to do, then please clarify exactly what it is that you are attempting to do.